# Failed to execute: 'control build' & Failed to execute goal: maven-compiler

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jboss, compiler-errors, openshift

My project works locally and it worked 3-4 hours ago also at the server. I did a large commit and now it's messed up. I already solved quite many error messages and this is what there is left. I am using "force_clean_build" marker so server downloads all the jars in the middle of the push, but immediately after the push the git bash says:

```
remote: [INFO] Compiling 30 source files to /var/lib/openshift/547b2214e0b8cd9044g83940/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/547b2214e0b8cd9044g83940/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/com/mvcproject/RowMapper/UserRowMapper.java:[4,53] error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.episode does not exist
remote: [INFO] 1 error
remote: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 31.508s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 09 16:30:41 EST 2014
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/142M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project javaproject: Compilation failure
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/547b2214e0b8cd9044g83940/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/com/mvcproject/RowMapper/UserRowMapper.java:[4,53] error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.episode does not exist
remote: [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote: [ERROR]
remote: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote: [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote: [ERROR]
remote: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/547b2214e0b8cd9044g83940/jbossews
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://547b2214e0b8cd9044g83940@javaproject-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/javaproject.git/639492e..ff379cc  master -> master
```

I have no idea what "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.episode" or "gear postreceive" is. That UserRowMapper has worked before this. I also removed my .m2 folder locally, but didn't figure out where it is at the server, but I guess "force clean build" will do the trick?

My pom.xml WITHOUT dependencies (because there is too much them) looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

... dependecies ....

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>javaproject</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <finalName>javaproject</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit I don't know much about java, but it looks like you are missing a dependency in your `pom.xml`. The package the compilation is complaining is missing looks to be provided by jaxb-osgi:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-osgi/2.2.1

Essentially add the below to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change the output of git bash. I added jaxb-osgi, compiled, all fine locally and then pushed it to openshift repo and errors are still the same ones.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a library import in one of my classes which I didn't know about. Don't even know what is it for. I guess I have been imported it by accident with auto-import. Everything OK now.